# AWS lambda function does not receive the caller origin url

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, function, aws-lambda, twilio

I am working with a twilio studio flow. In the studio flow i call my lambda function https://my-lambda.com/id=1.

In my lambda function i want to get the url of the website that called my function so I can validate it is being called from a twilio endpoint.

```
public async Task<APIGatewayHttpV2ProxyResponse> FunctionHandlerAsync(APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest request , ILambdaContext context)
{
    var callerUrl = // this is what I need.
    bool isFromTwilio = validator.Validate(callerUrl, querystrings, twilioSignature).
}
```

No host header is being passed in from the request headers.

Thank you

I tried using rawpath and lambda context but none of them returned the url of the website that called my function

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73156438/twilio-studio-flow-with-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway

Comment: If you want the url from where your lambda was called, you need the `Origin` header. The headers should be in the `Request.Headers` dictionary. If there is no `Origin` entry, the client didn't send one (which would be rather  unlikely if the request originated from a browser)